# Computing the differential of a function

Tags: calculus

I need to compute the differential of a function $y=e^x  \ln x$.

Here's what I did:
$$d\left( e^x  \ln x \right) = \left(e^x  \ln x + \frac{e^x}{ x} \right) dx.$$

Is that the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Recall the rule: $d(f(x))=f'(x)\; dx$. So, yes.

Comment: undeleted;;;;;;

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct.

Just as a suggestion, where you face expressions which only contain products, quotienst, powers, logarithmic differentitation uses to make life easier
$$y=e^x  \log (x) \implies \log(y)=x+\log(\log(x))$$ Differentiate both sides
$$\frac{y'}y=1+\frac{1}{x \log (x)}$$ Now, use
$$y'=y \times \left(\frac{y'}y \right)$$ replace and simplify to get the same result. As you see, I did not use the product rule at any time.